# Rails save xlsx templates in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to develop functionality that would allow me to save axslx files in the database.  Basically, I envision an EXCEL reporting sub-system.  Where you can create the Excel templates and save them in a Reports table.

I'm using the `gem 'panoramic'`.  It is allowing me to save the axslx files in the database!  But, in order for them to work, I have to have an entry in the routes and action in the controller.  I can just create them using multiple entries, like report1..report10.  But, that puts a limit on the number of reports.

This is the view code:

```
<% reportpath = 'report' + report.report_number.to_s + '.xlsx'  %>
<td><%= link_to "Download", report_path(reportpath), :class => 'btn btn-warning btn-xs' %></td>
```

This is the routes:

```
get "reports/report1"
get "reports/report2"
...
```

This is the controller code:

```
  def report1
   respond_to do |format|
     disposition =   'attachment; filename= ' + '"' + 'report1.xlsx" '

    format.xlsx {
      response.headers['Content-Disposition'] =  disposition
    }
  end
end

def report2
  respond_to do |format|
    disposition =   'attachment; filename= ' + '"' + 'report2.xlsx" '

    format.xlsx {
      response.headers['Content-Disposition'] =  disposition
    }
  end
end
```

Is there some way to use a single route and controller action?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If for some reason you cannot pass the number via parameter and you want to include it into route you may use [dynamic route segments](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments):

```
get "reports/:report_name" => 'reports#report', constraints: { report_name: /report[0-9]+/ }
```

And in controller

```
def report
  report_name = params[:report_name]
  respond_to do |format|
    disposition =   "attachment; filename=\"#{report_name}.xlsx\""
    format.xlsx {
      response.headers['Content-Disposition'] =  disposition
      render report_name
    }
  end
end
```

**Update**

In a bit cleaner way:

```
resources :reports, only: [:show]
```

and

```
def show
  report_name = params[:id]
  raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found') unless /report[0-9]+/.match report_name
  respond_to do |format|
    disposition =   "attachment; filename=\"#{report_name}.xlsx\""
    format.xlsx {
      response.headers['Content-Disposition'] =  disposition
      render report_name
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: ArgumentError: Regexp anchor characters are not allowed in routing requirements: /\Areport[0-9]+\z/

Comment: If I remove the constraint, I get: Missing template reports/report, application/report with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:xlsx], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee, :axlsx]}. Searched in:
  * "#<Panoramic::Resolver:0x007ffbb7a7c668>" - It's looking for reports/report instead of reports/report1

Comment: Oops, I've updated the answer - removed anchor characters and specified the template explicitly.

Comment: On a second thought this could be done cleaner by using default show method, I'll update the answer